# Summernote editor display issues

Tags: php

My Summernote editor is displaying the image insert link outside of the editor how to rectify it:

[image: example as how it looks]

I have added in the head:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  addeed in the body
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the script

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#description').summernote({
        height: 400
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: do you try to do something with height?

Comment: i have given height  as height: 400

Comment: try to remove the height and we'll see how it works